# Session attribute not working with useBean value

Tags: java, session, servlets, javabeans, jspx

I am currently creating a web application use java servlets and jspx pages. I have created a java class with a parameter when called with the class being LessonSelection(int owner). I know that you cannot use a bean with a parameter so I made an object of that class with the parameter and then added it to the session, then used that session attribute in the useBean.

I have an error coming up saying 'The value of the useBean class attribute ${selected} is invalid'

The useBean code is below.

```
<jsp:useBean class="${selected}" id="timetable" scope="session"/>
```

The java code is below.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("username", user);
session.setAttribute("id", id);
selected = new LessonSelection(id);
session.setAttribute("selected", selected);
dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/LessonTimetableView.jspx");
```

If you need any more of the code that I wrote, just ask thanks.

EDIT 1:

I thought I would check whether it is actually added to the session attribute and it is added. It is printed as 'model.LessonSelection@1457de3'. It still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` at `jsp:useBean` must be the package + class of your attribute! Suppose your `LessonSelection` is located in the package `com.test`. The code would be as follow:

```
<jsp:useBean class="com.test.LessonSelection" id="timetable" scope="session"/>
```

**Edit 1**

Try this:

```
<jsp:useBean type="com.test.LessonSelection" id="timetable" scope="session"/>
```

It seens that using type, the JSP wont instantiate it for your, it'll just look from the bean of the given type in the given scope. See it [here](http://www-it.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/courses/WDB/references/JSP%20syntax/syntaxref08.html).

Comment: Thank you for that but I have a parameter for the LessonSelection class so it will not allow me to do that. I have tried class="com.test.LessonSelection(1)" but that gives another error

Comment: @HasanTariq, try to create the default constructor, and see if it works

Comment: This is for an assignment and my lecturer gave the class like that. I don't think I can change it

Comment: @HasanTariq, see my edit, and try to change `class` to `type`

Comment: I will try to use type but then how would I give the owner parameter in?

Comment: See the documentation...When you use type, it wont instantied it, just located the bean in the scope. As you are adding it before, you can use only type.

Comment: I have tried type and it comes up with another error

Comment: @HasanTariq, could you post the log file? and an excerpt from the JSP?